# Error de punto flotante al obtener el resultado de dos numeros negativos elevados en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero realizar la siguiente operación

```
SELECT POWER(-0.616666,-1.6441441441441)
```

pero me devuelve el siguiente error

```
Msg 3623, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
An invalid floating point operation occurred.
```

ya intente hacer cast a ambos numeros y convert, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error, hay una manera de llevar acabo esta funcion, pero siendo numeros de tipo flotante, que no sean int

saludos

**UPDATE**

Quiero realizar esta linea en mi Store Procedure

```
select POWER((@TEMP_FX_TASAS_DXVENCER/360.00),(365.00/@TEMP_FX_TASAS_DXVENCER)) AS POW
```

pero me ha salido el error antes mencionado, como puedo llevar dicha operacion?, en ambas variables a veces obtengo un numero negativo, saludos

Comment: que quieres hacer? el segundo parametro que recibe es la cantidad de decimales que quieres el resultado, no debes hacer algo como `SELECT POWER(-0.616666,12) + POWER(-1.644144144144 , 12)`?? puedes ver el [manual](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql)

Comment: Hola @JackNavaRow, estoy llevando acabo un store procedure, hay una linea con la siguiente informacion ya actualizada, saludos

Comment: pero que quieres hacer, tu pregunta es muy confusa , cuando le colocar , al POWER te lo tomara como segundo parametro, he alli el problema

Answer (score 3):

el problema en realidad es matemático, ese resultado daría un número complejo pero no tienen representación en SQL. Deberías plantear si tiene sentido en el dominio de tu aplicación que @TEMP_FX_TASAS_DXVENCER pueda ser negativo.

Comment: Gracias master!!! ..